# Display IMAGE data in Data Studio Community Visualization

Tags: image, visualization, looker-studio

I'm trying to display IMAGE data from a data source in my community visualization. The image is perfectly shown in a standard table vis, but not in my own.

I found that IMAGE data comes with 2 urls, one of them is same to url in the data source, and the other one points to googleusercontent.com
Both urls are accessible from a browser. However when i add IMG tag to the vis html body with any of those addresses, the picture is not shown.

Here are part of the message with data coming from a data source

```
export const message = {
    "tables": {
        "DEFAULT": [
            {
                "image": [
                    "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=37.56448,-0.9671933&zoom=8&size=100x100&maptype=roadmap&key=MY_API_KEY  https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/aAtBhrO5c1UI1MKq-vAI0s2XW-W0u9IjCYpV204FYmDrwkQm7iYDEt1k1zIijlw3bFkTcezb4cjKRFkSlO9h0gMCiu2EMVpPqZJcARjrcLKDGgdhEp44phjW0dCRkD8ojZAZDkSv4sjgV3643BaSjsRYfc6zUV6mhq2EYGNHWB5A_QAKjyhP6gbB2_a_yU5Ew-pkx-1pPBEnMpeax2KihPHTCtuTrhmMlzlW7_eRQVtwKPY  "
                ]
```

and the IMAGE tag I create

```
<img src = "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/aAtBhrO5c1UI1MKq-vAI0s2XW-W0u9IjCYpV204FYmDrwkQm7iYDEt1k1zIijlw3bFkTcezb4cjKRFkSlO9h0gMCiu2EMVpPqZJcARjrcLKDGgdhEp44phjW0dCRkD8ojZAZDkSv4sjgV3643BaSjsRYfc6zUV6mhq2EYGNHWB5A_QAKjyhP6gbB2_a_yU5Ew-pkx-1pPBEnMpeax2KihPHTCtuTrhmMlzlW7_eRQVtwKPY">
```

Does anyone know how to show image from a data source, just like in a table vis?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently(as of Nov 2019) not supported via Community Viz. See [Community Viz Limitation](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/visualization/issues): "Requests for external resources are restricted via a Content Security Policy (CSP)."

Comment: in fact i'm not using external resource, the url in IMG tag is created by data studio to it's own resources. Still not working, so unfair...